# C code undefined behaviour - realloc of struct in func

Tags: c, realloc

Being non-expert in c-coding, I have dared to start writing a code. The preliminary version of the code works as expected (when complied with gcc -lm). However, when I am trying to just compile it with -fopenmp option of the compiler since I want to make some parts of the code parallel, the code crashes - segmentation fault. I want to emphasize that I have not introduced any pragmas yet - I just compile with the -fopenmp option and the code crashes. However, when I try to run this code on different linux machine - it works.

I tried to use debugger to see at which place of my code the segmentation fault happens.   It seems like the problems start when I try to re-allocate the structures in the function which were previously allocated in main ().

Here is the structure:

```
typedef struct 
{
        Bond bond; // structure bond
        int f; // the lenghth of the fragment
        int *fragment;
} Fragment;
```

First, I allocated it in main () and pass it to the function:

```
Fragment fragments3[NBONDS];
for (i=0;i<NBONDS;i++) {
        fragments3[i].fragment = malloc (1*sizeof(int));
        fragments3[i].f = 0;
        fragments3[i].bond = bonds[i];
}
// to fill up the allocated fragments with the values
fragmentation(coordinates, NATOMS, NBONDS, bonds, fragments3);
```

Then when I start using this allocated array of structs in function fragmentation the segmentation fault occurs:

```
void fragmentation(Atom *coordinates, int NATOMS, int NBONDS, Bond *bonds, Fragment *fragments3) {

int mm, i, ll, j;
for (mm=0;mm<NBONDS;mm++) {
        (fragments3)[mm].bond.atom1 = bonds[mm].atom1; (fragments3)[mm].bond.atom1 = bonds[mm].atom1; 
        for (i=0;i<coordinates[bonds[mm].atom1-1].nn;i++) {
                if (coordinates[bonds[mm].atom1-1].n[i] != bonds[mm].atom2) {
                        (fragments3)[mm].fragment[(fragments3)[mm].f]= coordinates[bonds[mm].atom1-1].n[i];
                        (fragments3)[mm].f= (fragments3)[mm].f + 1;
                        (fragments3)[mm].fragment = (int *) realloc( (fragments3)[mm].fragment, ((fragments3)[mm].f+1)*sizeof(int) ) ;

                }
        }
}
.......
}
```

Any hints or advise would be helpful. I have to emphasize that the same crash happens when I allocate in the main like:

```
Fragment **fragments3 = malloc(NBONDS * sizeof (*fragments3));
...
fragmentation(coordinates, NATOMS, NBONDS, bonds, &fragments3);
```

and use it in function as :

```
(*fragments3).f = ...
```

Yes, sure, these are the structures:

```
typedef struct {
        char El[3];
        double xyz[3];
        int t;    
        int n[23]; 
        int nn; 
} Atom;

typedef struct {
        int atom1;
        int atom2;
        int angle;
} Bond;
```

In the main I initiated them in the following way:

```
Atom *coordinates = malloc(1 * sizeof *coordinates);
Bond *bonds = malloc(1*sizeof *bonds);
```

(later these are filled via function)

Comment: Could you post `Atom` And `Bond` structs and an init of buffers?

Comment: Are you sure that `bonds[mm].atom1-1` gives always no negative numbers?

Comment: Have you tried feeding it to a memory analyzer such as AddressSanitizer or valgrind?

Comment: I tried your code with a simple inited structure and all is working well. It seems is something related to your data in `Coordinates` and `bonds` array, not to realloc function

Comment: I saw your edit. After the int of coordinates and bonds , do you realloc them? I'm asking this because of you are allocating a single structure and in your code you use NBONDS as the max dim of the arrays.

Comment: Thank you: Yes, after init of coordinates and bonds I reallocate them in another function. And, yes I am sure that bonds[mm].atom1-1 gives always positive int numbers.

Comment: Could you add `NULL` return check to each `malloc` `realloc` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a bug in the code when following the advise to check every malloc allocation. The problem was in the structure coordinates, namely in coordinates.n The point is that I used counting with this variable: coordinates.n++. Since I did not put 0 at the beginning I got some strange number in this and the whole thing went wrong.

But to get it I had to check 1000 lines of the code..

Thank you again!